# Sorting Backbone collections prior to render

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

**EDIT:** To sort a Backbone Collection, you simply need to specify a comparator (without defining a sortBy mechanism) as follows: 
                    `dictionary.add(entry);
                    dictionary.comparator = 'word';`

---

I am having trouble sorting a collection that new models are pushed to using .add(), (not pre-loaded). Ive tried to use underscore's sort method below

```
 var sorted = _(dictionary).sortBy("word");
```

but I can't get the collection to respond.  Below is my code.  Ive commented out my non-functioning code at the bottom.

```
(function($){

    //---------SINGLE ENTRY MODEL----------
            var Entry = Backbone.Model.extend({
                defaults: function(){
                    return{
                        word: '',
                        definition: ''
                    }
                }
            });

        //------------ENTRY MODEL COLLECTION------------
            var EntryList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
                model: Entry
            });

        //-----INSTANCIATE COLLECTION----
        var dictionary = new EntryList();

        //-----SINGLE ENTRY VIEW------
        var EntryView = Backbone.View.extend({
            model: new Entry(),
            tagName:'div',

            events:{
                'click .edit': 'edit',
                'click .delete': 'delete',
                'keypress .definition': 'updateOnEnter'
            },

            delete: function(ev){
                ev.preventDefault;
                dictionary.remove(this.model);
            },

            edit: function(ev){
                ev.preventDefault;
                this.$('.definition').attr('contenteditable', true).focus();

            },
            close: function(){
                var definition = this.$('.definition').text();
                this.model.set('definition', definition);
                this.$('.definition').attr('contenteditable', false).blur();

            },

            updateOnEnter: function(ev){
                if(ev.which == 13){
                    this.close();
                }
            },

            initialize: function(){
                this.template = _.template($("#dictionary_template").html());

            },

            render: function(){
                this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
                return this;
            }
        });

        //--------------DICTIONARY VIEW------------
        var DictionaryView = Backbone.View.extend({
            model: dictionary,
            el: $('#entries'),

            initialize: function(){
                this.model.on('add', this.render, this);
                this.model.on('remove', this.render, this);

            },

            render: function(){
                var self = this;
                self.$el.html('');
                _.each(this.model.toArray(), function(entry, i){
                    self.$el.append((new EntryView({model: entry})).render().$el);
                });

                return this;
            }
        });


        //-------BINDING DATA ENTRY TO NEW MODEL VIEW-------
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#new-entry').submit(function(ev){
                var entry = new Entry({word: $('#word').val(), definition: $('#definition').val() });

                dictionary.add(entry);

                //var sorted = _(dictionary).sortBy("word");
                //console.log(sorted.toJSON());

                console.log(dictionary.toJSON());

                $('.form-group').children('input').val('');

                return false;
            });
            var appView = new DictionaryView();
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: is there a better way than simply using dictionary.comparator="word" ?

Comment: _() returns a new array, which you sort, it does nothing to the object underneath  which cannot really be sorted according to ES5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is that you're applying a straight-Underscore.js `sortBy` to `dictionary` which is not a `collection` in the sense Underscore.js understands it. Rather it's a `Backbone.Collection` (and it doesn't help you that J. Ashkenaz wrote both Backbone and Underscore.js). So, unfortunately, running `sortBy` on `dictionary` is going to give you unpredictable results (since you have all kinds of other parent properties on a `Backbone.Collection` besides the `models` prop. So...

### Using `sort`

I think the *easiest* and probably most stable solution is to use `Backbone.Collection.sort()`. The beauty of it all is that once you provide a `comparator` the Backbone will sort the collection for you automatically (I'm not gibing you, check out the [docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-sort)). (Btw, you can disable this functionality on `Backbone.Collection.add()`, by passing in `{ sort: false }`.)

### Using a comparator

According to the [docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-comparator) (emphasis mine):

> A comparator can be defined as a sortBy (pass a function that takes a single argument), as a sort (pass a comparator function that expects two arguments), or as a **string indicating the attribute to sort by**.

In your case if you add the line

```
dictionary.comparator = "word";
```

before your first add function (like after your instantiate the collection) you should be all set.

Comment: all i had to do was add the comparator; I didnt even have to apply a sort.  many thanks